Login with Facebook, redirecting to wrong URL when using Authorize attribute
I have following code for external login with google and facebook in my account controller
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider)
        {
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account");
            var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            return Challenge(properties, provider);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
        {
            var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
            }

            // Get the external user information
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var name = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
            var provider = info.LoginProvider;
            // Check if the user already exists
            var user = await _userService.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                // Create a new user
                user = new User { Name = name, Email = email, IsActive = true, PasswordHash = "" };
                if(provider == "Google")
                {
                    user.IsGoogleSignup = true; 
                }
                else if(provider == "Facebook")
                {
                    user.IsFacebookSignup = true;
                }
                await _userService.CreateUserAsync(user);
                
            }

            var token = _userService.GenerateJwtToken(user);

            var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            };

            Response.Cookies.Append("AuthToken", token, cookieOptions);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

my home controller
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

With signin with google it's working fine and I'm getting redirect to my site index page
but with facebook it's adding "#=" at the end of my url which causing error and hit is not going to home controller
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

here if I'm removing Authorized then hit is coming and I'm able to redirect to my index page.
I saw solutions, I can not use javascript to remove it as my page isn't even loading due to wrong url
What can be done?

You could try following to modify the redirectUri in  OnTicketReceived event.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "xxx";
    options.ClientSecret = "xxxx";
    options.Events.OnTicketReceived = async context =>
    {
        // Customize the login URL
        var oldUri = context.ReturnUri;
        var newUri = oldUri.Replace("#_=_", "");
        context.ReturnUri = newUri;
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});


[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account");
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
{
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }

    // Get the external user information
    var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    var name = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
    var provider = info.LoginProvider;
    // Check if the user already exists
    var user = await _userService.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);

    if (user == null)
    {
        // Create a new user
        user = new User { Name = name, Email = email, IsActive = true, PasswordHash = "" };
        if (provider == "Google")
        {
            user.IsGoogleSignup = true;
        }
        else if (provider == "Facebook")
        {
            user.IsFacebookSignup = true;
        }
        await _userService.CreateUserAsync(user);

    }

    var token = _userService.GenerateJwtToken(user);

    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
    };

    Response.Cookies.Append("AuthToken", token, cookieOptions);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

